ASP.NET WebAPI net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT (Ошибка при выполнение запроса fetch)
На некоторых компьютерах возникает ошибка при выполнение запросов GET, POST, DELETE (другие не проверялись) к WebAPI ASP.NET Core. Ошибка net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT (ответ не содержит ничего кроме самой ошибки). Проблема наблюдается только на некоторых устройствах (на моем пк, например, все работает корректно). API размещено на сервере IIS.
В API используется CORS. API размещено на условном хосте https://api.myhost.ru, а фронт, откуда отправляется запрос, на https://sub1.myhost.ru.
builder.Services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("DefaultPolicy", builder =>
{
    builder.WithOrigins("https://sub1.myhost.ru", "https://sub2.myhost.ru");
    builder.AllowAnyMethod();
}));

Пример одного из методов контроллера, при запросе которого возникает ошибка:
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetTaskAttachments([BindRequired, FromQuery(Name = "task-id")] Guid taskId)
{
    try
    {
        var taskAttachments = await context.TaskAttachments.Where(taskAttachment => taskAttachment.TaskId == taskId).ToListAsync();
        return Ok(taskAttachments);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        logger.LogError(ex.UseRequest(Request), "{message}", ex.Message);
        return StatusCode(500, new { Exception = ex.GetType().ToString(), ex.Message });
    }
}

Вот так я отправляю запрос к API:
fetch(`https://api.myhost.ru/public/task/attachments?task-id=${model.get('id')}&api-version=2.0`).then(res => {
   res.json().then(data => {
       ...
   });
});

Вот содержимое файлов web.config веб-сайта и конкретного приложения соответственно:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <remove name="WebDAV" />  
            <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
            <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
            <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
            <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" responseBufferLimit="0" />
            <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
            <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>

.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
        <system.webServer>
            <handlers>
                <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
            </handlers>
            <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\PublicApi.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
        </system.webServer>
    </location>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: 15B5E1A2-3903-4840-9AAF-46030CE5A314-->

Для комментария SwaD




Где именно возникает ошибка? На клиенте или на сервере? Ошибка возникает всегда или плавающая? Что в отладчике говорит вкладка network? Сервер при ошибке видит вообще запрос или он до него не доходит? Ответы на эти вопросы укажите в самом вопросе и желательно в вопрос добавить полный текст ошибки со стектрейсом(если есть)

@SwaD, добавил. На тех устройствах, где обнаружилась ошибка, она возникает фактически постоянно.

@SwaD, так же характерно то, что ошибка на одном устройстве клиента возникает постоянно, на другом не возникает вовсе. Также на "проблемных" устройствах при отправке GET запроса по указанному адресу напрямую через поисковую строку (просто в браузере) все нормально отрабатывает.

Похоже на то, что сами запросы не доходят до сервера и где то рубятся по дороге. Это либо что то на самом устройстве, либо в сети, куда устройство подключено. Так же может сервер блокирует подключения из той сети, откуда запроса идут. Так что искать надо в этой стороне, а не в коде.

Отдельно еще можно попробовать посмотреть(залогировать), а что в этот момент на сервере творится. Получает ли запрос сервер(где то в иис было логирование входящего трафика). Срабатывает ли код на сервере, отдает ли ответ.

ответ не содержит ничего кроме самой ошибки - это не ответ от сервера, это техническая ошибка, означает что запрос был отправлен, но ответ от сервера не получен и ожидание ответа прекратилось по таймауту.

@aepot, ну то, что это не ответ, я понимаю. Меня больше волнует вопрос: по какому принципу сбрасываются эти запросы. Потому что идентичные запросы где-то отрабатывают, а где-то нет.

Не думаю, что в этом виноват сам сервер.
